# Kullback–Leibler divergence between two multivariate t distributions with different degrees of freedom?

Tags: kullback-leibler, t-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I want to calculate the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

[image]

between two [multivariate $t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution) distributions with different degrees of freedom (say $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$), but same location and scale matrix, for arbitrary dimensions,

[image]

How can I deal with the multivariate integral in the KL divergence? Is there a closed-form solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the following post:

[Kullback Leibler divergence between two multivariate t distributions](https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/DKLt)

The authors reduce the dimension of the integral from $p$ (in your notation) to 1, which seems to be easier to handle. The post contains numerical examples in R.

[image]

**Edit**. As mentioned by @utobi in a comment, `it is not a closed-form solution since it still involves univariate numerical integration. However, it's better than a vanilla multivariate integration.` Indeed, this solution is a more "numerically tractable" alternative to multivariate integration, but not a closed-form one.